# Cancel external service that runs PR status checks when PR is abandoned in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

We have an external service that gets triggered with every pull request to our repo in Azure DevOps, runs checks, and posts a [status check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-status?view=azure-devops#pull-request-status) back to the PR. This service is very resource heavy. Sometimes PR authors abandon the PR before the service finishes running. We are trying to find a way we can be notified of the PR being abandoned so we can also cancel orchestration and save resources. Is there a mechanism to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We are trying to find a way we can be notified of the PR being abandoned so we can also cancel orchestration and save resources.

You could set the notification in Azure Devops **Project Settings -> Notification -> New Subscription**.

You could select the **A pull request is created or updated** and set the filter and target users.

When a pull request is Abandoned, the users will get the notification email.

On the other hand, you can also get the Pull Request Status via the Rest API: [Pull Requests - Get Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=6.0
```

[image]

**Update:**

You could try to create a custom workflow(e.g. [Power Automate](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/)) to check the Pull Request status.

Here is an example:

[image]

**Explanation:**

1.The **Recurrence** action is set 10 minutes interval(you could set the suitable interval ). Then the flow will execute every 10 minutes to check the pull request status.

2.The **Send Http Request to Azure Devops**  action is used to run the API above to get the Pull Request status.

3.The **Condition** action is used to compare the response and the value.

Comment: Thanks! I think what we need is a service hook that publishes this event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#pull-request-updated

Comment: Hi @Sunny-Dee. Thanks for your update. In Azure devops service hook, Status changed will contain all status.It cannot judge whether it is equal to abandoned. Please refer to my update. You could try to create a custom workflow to get the status and send the request to your service

Comment: Hi @Sunny-Dee. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.